# How to create a button that clears my form

Tags: php, html, reset

I am writing a program that gets information from forms using AJAX, and I was wondering if there was a way to make a button that clears the form and sort of resets the form. Right now if you press a button, the text won't disappear, but Im hoping to make a home button that would make the text disappear. I am just going to post my .html file because I think thats all we need. Let me know if there is more code you need. I tried making a reset button but it didn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assignment8</title>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script>

function getXML() {
        var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
        if (!xmlHttp) {
                alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
                return;
        }

        xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                        // Get XML Document
                        var xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML;

                        // Variable for our output
                        var output = '';

                        // Build output by parsing XML
                        dinos = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title');

                        for (i = 0; i < dinos.length; i++) {
                                output += dinos[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                        }

                        // Get div object
                        var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoXML');

                        // Set the div's innerHTML
                        divObj.innerHTML = output;
                }
        }

        xmlHttp.open("GET", "dino.xml", true);
        xmlHttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml")
        xmlHttp.send();
}


function getJSON() {
        var xmlHttp = xmlHttpObjCreate();
        if (!xmlHttp) {
                alert("The browser doesn't support this action.");
        return;
        }
        xmlHttp.onload = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                        // Get Response Text
                        var response = xmlHttp.responseText;

                        // Prints the JSON string
                        console.dir(response);

                        // Get div object
                        var divObj = document.getElementById('dinoJSON');

                        // We used JSON.parse to turn the JSON string into an object
                        var responseObject = JSON.parse(response);

                        // This is our object
                        console.dir(responseObject)

                        // We can use that object like so:
                        for (i in responseObject) {
 divObj.innerHTML += "<p>"+responseObject[i].name + " lived during the " + responseObject[i].pet + "period.</p>";
}  
}
}
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "json.php", true);
        xmlHttp.send();
} 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h3> Dinosaur Web Services </h3>
<div id="home"></div>
<button type="reset" value="Reset"> Home</button>

<div id="dinoJSON"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="getJSON();"> JSON Dinos</button>


 <div id="dinoXML"></div>
 <button type="button" onclick="getXML();"> XML Dinos</button>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Where would I add the form tags in my code?

Comment: you OP `How to create a button that clears my form`. so must have a form!!!

Comment: I don't have the tags in my code though, where would you add them?

Comment: @sgt I added form tags in my code but it still doesn't work

Comment: now it will reset the form automatically.

Comment: @sgt it doesn't work though

Comment: @sgt any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your reset-button should already do this, if its within the `<form></form>` or has the "form"-attribute, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp)

Comment: It doesn't work, the text thats displayed when I press a different button stays on the screen when I press the home button

Comment: Well, i dont see any forms in your html-code so i can't help further.

Comment: Where would you add a form

Comment: Somewhere within the body maybe.

Comment: Now you have a form, but i still don't see any input-fields?!

Comment: How do I create those? can you please explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the default reset button, if it is in between the form tag or you can use jquery to do this for you.
You just have to add an event on the click event of the home button and u can achieve what you want.

this is a reference which u can take

$(".reset").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], input[type="password"], textarea").val("");
});

Add all other fields which u want to clear on click of the home button